# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'author' of undefined

Tags: angular6, jsondb

I get this error when i want to save changes to sever " add a comment" by clicking Submit button thanks for helping

```
onSubmit() {      
this.comment.author = this.author;
this.comment.rating = this.rating;
this.comment.comment = this.comment1;


this.comment.date = new Date().toISOString();
console.log(this.comment);
this.dishcopy.comments.push(this.comment);
this.dishcopy.save()
  .subscribe(dish => { this.dish = dish; console.log(this.dish); });

  }
```

template code:

```
    <div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="author" [(ngModel)]="author">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="rating" [(ngModel)]='rating'>
      <mat-option value="1">1</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="2">2</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="3">3</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="4">4</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="5">5</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="comment" [(ngModel)]="comment1"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

More deteils:
this is Comment.ts code:

```
export class Comment {
rating: number;
comment: string;
author: string;
date: string;}
```

and I  instantiate it by:

```
import { Comment } from '../shared/comment';
...
comment:Comment;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have never instantiated `this.comment`, so when you try to access its `author` property you find it undefined.

add this code to the beginning of `onSubmit()`

```
this.comment = new Comment();
```

Keep in mind that if you don't need some checks or logic operations into `onSubmit()` you could bind directly `this.comment`'s properties to template variables

**EDIT**

This code `comment:Comment;` is not an instantiation, is 
 a declaration. You need this:

```
comment: Comment = new Comment();
```

or this by letting TypeScript infer the type:

```
comment = new Comment();
```